# How can I get the avg of a string of numbers without any modules in Python?

Tags: python, string

If i have a string that's like '1234BC' I want to get 2.5. Or if I have 'me123456' I get 3.5? I tried using modules but it not work at all.

I tried this:

I tried this

```
avg = 0
sum = 0    
for n in numbers:
    sum = sum + n
avg = sum / len(numbers)
```

Comment: What did you try using?

Comment: will you have floats in your string?

Comment: avg = 0
sum = 0    
for n in numbers:
    sum = sum + n
avg = sum / len(numbers)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
>>> s = '1234ab'
>>> numbers = [int(x) for x in s if x.isdigit()]
>>> total = sum(numbers)
>>> avg = float(total) / len(numbers)
>>> avg
2.5
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a='me123456'
b=[ int(x) for x in a if x.isdigit() ]
float(sum(b))/len(b)
```

In the above code, the for loop will iterate over the string and if check condition that it digit or not. isdigit() function will return true, if its digit else return false. creates a list b of all digit.

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer. Code-only answers are sometimes good enough, but code+explanation answers are always better

Answer (score 0):

So for this question it appears you're assuming all digits are single digit integers. You can search through every character in the string and check it against all single digit integers. If it's a match, just add it to a "stringInts" list. I'll leave the averaging function up to you once you have that list ;).

Here's my suggested code to create stringInts. BTW, my python is a bit rusty so there may be a syntax error or two.

```
stringInts = []
for i in "string":
    if i == (0 or 1 or 2 or 3 or 4 or 5 or 6 or 7 or 8 or 9)
        stringInts.append(i)
```

Then just average that list. Comment if you need help with the average function

Comment: Or like Hackaholic said use isdigit. My method is a wee bit messier

Answer (score 0):

here you go dude ...

```
import re
s = '1234ab'
print reduce(lambda x,y:x/float(y), [
                      reduce(lambda x,y:x+y,[int(x) for x in s if x.isdigit()]),
                      len(re.findall("\d",s))
                           ])
```

and bonus points if you can explain it to the teacher